# Subtraction in database from another table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table called books which contains the names of the books and another table called students.

When in table students, a book is being issued. I need to reduce the quantity of a book in books table.

Comment: Do we imagine the schema or you will provide that?

Comment: I have called the books into the dropdown menu of student page form, all i need to do is .... when submit button of student page is clicked the id of the books in student page should reduce a book count in books table ........ any schema u can use ... all i need is an idea ... i am a beginner

Comment: read the books table with book id and then update the count to count - 1 for that book id if you are storing the count of books in your books table.

Comment: Could u help me out and write the codes if possible

Comment: You would use an `UPDATE` statement. In a simple example, `UPDATE books_table SET book_count= book_count-1 WHERE title = 'something'`. Look up some examples on the internet. You should also store which student has that copy of the book somewhere in your database.

Comment: @prayanshakya I suggest you to read basics about SQL first. You are not clear on your DB schema and you don't know basic UPDATE statement. Expecting someone else to do your work will not help you in your career. Put some effort to learn. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the following:

- in your `book` table, a column called `id` stores a unique identifier per book,
- and in your `student` table, a column called `borrowed_book_id` stores the id of a book that the student has borrowed, or `NULL` if there is no such book.

Then what you want to know is the number of books in the `book` table that do not have a corresponding entry in the `student` table.

You should be able to do this by joining the `book` table against the `student` table and look for rows of `book` where the `id` does not match any entry in the `borrowed_book_id` column of the `student` table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM book
LEFT JOIN student ON book.id = student.borrowed_book_id
WHERE student.borrowed_book_id IS NULL
```

Notice the use of `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`, because we want to return all rows in the "left table" (`book`) regardless of whether there is a matching row in the "right table" (`student`). When there is no such matching row in `student` for a given book (i.e., when no student has borrowed the book), the columns of `student` in the joined table will be `NULL` which allows us to count them.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this, and you will likely need to adapt this query to your schema. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all i needed was an idea .... i will be implementing it now :)